# Python. File Operations

Tags: python

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            print "copying"
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore=None)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
def main ():
    #path to input
    src="/home/user/abcd"
    #here path to output
    dst="/home/user/dirtest"
    copytree(src,dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I copy the file in the destination folder if it already exists? The newer file should be renamed to something like filename.x.ext.

E.g.- If I try to copy `newfile.jpg` and it already exists in the folder, it should get copied as `newfile.1.jpg`. If `newfile.1.jpg` also exists already, the new file should be named `newfile.2.jpg` and so on

Comment: First, do you understand what that code is doing?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I undestand

Answer (score 2):

```
def getUniqueName(destPath):
   d = destPath[:]
   count = 0
   while os.path.exists(d):
      count += 1 
      parts = os.path.splitext(d)
      d = "%s.%s%s"%(parts[0],count,parts[1])
   return d
```

I think that would work

then just call it as

```
shutil.copy2(s, getUniqueName(d))
```

wont help when you do `shutil.copytree`

Comment: d = "%s.%s%s"%(parts[0],count,parts[1]) wont work unless d = "%s.%d.%s"%(parts[0],count,parts[1])  `%s.%d.%s`

Comment: parts contains ["/some/path/to/base_file_name",".ext"]  (so it includes the dot from the original exception)